# Setting a new column based on another column, 3 options

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I try to fix an embarrassing problem in Python Pandas. I want to add a new column, and depending on another column get the new values.

```
signal  nom
0       value is 0
1       value is outcome of some calculations
-1      value is outcome of some other calculations
```

I thought of using np.where - but I believe this has only the possibility to use 2 different outcomes (and I have 3).

I tried using a sequential approach, first check the col1 for the existence of a "1" and set the newcol based on this. Followed by a check if col1 is "-1", and input values based on this. But this overwrites.

I tried setting the new col with one line, but this gives True/False output.

```py
df['nom'] = (df.signal[df.signal ==1] * -10000) | (df.signal[df.signal ==-1] *30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for scalars by conditions and multiple by column `signal`:

```
m1 = df.signal == 1
m2 = df.signal == -1
df['nom'] = np.select([m1, m2], [-10000, 30], 0) * df.signal
```